# Using Python to delete rows in a csv file that contain certain chars

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that I'm trying to clean up. I am trying to look at the first column and delete any rows that have anything other than chars for that row in the first column (I'm working on cleaning up rows where the first column has a ^ or . for now). It seems all my attempts either do nothing or nuke the whole csv file.

Interestingly enough, I have code that can identify the problem rows and it seems to work fine

```
def FindProblemRows():
    with open('Data.csv') as csvDataFile:
        ProblemRows = []
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(csvDataFile)]
        length = len(data)
        for i in range (0,length):
            if data[i][0].find('^')!=-1 or data[i][0].find('.')!=-1:
                ProblemRows.append(i)
    return (ProblemRows)
```

Below I have my latest three failed attempts. Where am I going wrong and what should I change? Which of these comes closest?

```
'''
def Clean():
with open("Data.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    Problems = FindProblemRows()
    data = list(csv.reader(f))
    length = len(data)
    for row in data:
        for i in Problems:
            for j in range (0, length):
                if row[j] == i:
                    writer.writerow(row)
                    Problems.remove(i)






def Clean():
    Problems = FindProblemRows()
    with open('Data.csv') as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
        data = [row for row in csv.reader(csvDataFile)]
        length = len(data)
        width = len(data[0])
    with open("Data.csv","r") as csvFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader( csvFile )

    with open("CleansedData.csv","w") as csvResult:
        csvWrite = csv.writer( csvResult )
        for i in Problems:
            for j in range (0, length):
                if data[j] == i:
                    del data[j]
        for j in range (0, length):
            csvWrite.writerow(data[j])

      '''



def Clean():
     with open("Data.csv", 'r') as infile , open("CleansedData.csv", 'w') as outfile:
         data = [row for row in infile]
         for row in infile:
             for column in row:
                 if "^" not in data[row][0]:
                     if "." not in data[row][0]:
                         outfile.write(data[row])
```

***Update***

Now I have:

```
def Clean():
    df = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
    df =  df['^' not in df.Symbol]
    df =  df['.' not in df.Symbol]
```

but I get KeyError: True

Shouldn't that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check whether the column `Symbol` *contains* any of the characters of interest. Method `contains` takes a regular expression:

```
bad_rows = df.Symbol.str.contains('[.^]')
df_clean = df[~bad_rows]
```